# Making arrow heads smaller globally

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In TikZ, single arrows between nodes can be scaled down using the scale command, for instance:

`\draw[-{>[scale=0.5]}](A)--(B);`

I would like all arrows in my entire document to have smaller heads. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Put `\tikzset{arrows={[scale=0.5]}}` in your preamble.